# How to get pixel rgb values using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to find all red pixels in an image and create my own image with just the red pixels. So far I have been experimenting with matplotlib as I am very new to it.

```
def find_red_pixels(map, upper_threshold=100, lower_threshold =50):
    """Finds all red pixels of the "map" image and outputs a binary image file "map-red-pixels.jpg" """
    red_map = []
    for row in map:
        for pixel in row:
            print(pixel)
```

I am brand new to image manipulating and have tried this, however I do not understand what the values [0.0.01] etc. mean which is outputted as pixels. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing to understand is the way the image is represented in an array when it is read in. Here I read in a 320x160 image of a rainbow:

[image]

```
>>> img = plt.imread('rainbow.png')
>>> img.shape
    (160, 320, 4)
```

This shows the dimensions of the array - note the last element of the tuple is `4`. These values represent the red pixel values, the green pixel values, the blue pixel values, and the transparency or alpha values.

We want to find pixels which have a certain red value, so we're just interested in the first of these. Let's split these out so we can just work with them:

```
>>> r = img[:,:,0]
```

This isolates the portion of the array relating to the redness of the pixel values, represented by a value between `0` and `1`. We now want to isolate the locations of the pixels which have a certain redness value. We can use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for this, finding the elements in our new array `r` which have values of over `0.5` (this value can be altered to fit your requirements of `upper_threshold` and `lower_threshold`), and replacing these with a value of `1`, and `0` otherwise; creating a binary image.

```
>>> binary_img = np.where(r > 0.5, 1, 0)
```

Finally, we just need to save this image, using `plt.imsave`:

```
>>> plt.imsave('rainbow_red.png', binary_img , cmap='gray')
```

Giving the following result:

[image]

Comment: I think you have actually caught the red, orange and yellow pixels.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I assumed this was the intention of the `upper_threshold=100, lower_threshold=50` arguments in the OP's question; to capture all pixels with a red value of greater than 0.5

Comment: It may well be I was going by the comment that said OP was looking for red pixels. I guess OP will question it if unhappy with the result. You have my vote anyway.